# Extending OSM database with new data

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap, database, osm2pgsql

I want to add a new table inside my OSM database with extra data for every restaurant, and then when retrieving the places join the table by the `"osm_id"`, is this possible and if yes, any tips or instructions?

Comment: what have you tried ?

Comment: don't forget that `osm_id` is not a unique key, can change through time and, worst, can be recycled.